# How to save the generated table response in a excel file in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, file-upload, web

I have some data in database and through some JSPs and servlets i have made such a web application which have interface .Through interface i can select column name of table in database and type keyword in next text box and can search those rows which contains that keyword which is in that particular column.I have used bootstrap table for seeing output in tabular format.
I want that if user clicks save button which is at bottom of table a popup window opens and he can type the name  and selects location and file gets saved.

all other things like fetching of data and displaying there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSSFRow to parse ur jsp list to an excel sheet in java

```
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
```

Then u need to create a header for the excel sheet

//FOR HEADERS

```
HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("NAME");
```

Now u will fill the data in the columns depending on the list size.

//FOR REST OF THE LIST

```
    int rownum = 1;
    for (YourObject obj : listOfObjects) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++); 
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(obj.getID());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(obj.getName());
    }
```

Writing data to a xls file

```
 try {    

                 ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                 workbook.write(outByteStream);

                 byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

                 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

                 response.setContentLength(outArray.length);

                 response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching

                 response.setHeader("Pragma","cache");

                 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","private");

                 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.xls");

                 OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                 outStream.write(outArray);

                 outStream.flush();

                 outStream.close();

                 System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   
                 e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {    
                 e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for your help.I am newbie to this concept and i want to knowwhere to save this code (i mean in jsp ) but do ineed to put those upload button and save button in a form and in action i have to write this particular jsp or something else???

Comment: Please explain me once i promise i will try to enhance my knowledge and share it further. Do i need to put above code in a single jsp or servlet?

Comment: and where the xls file is getting saved

Comment: yes it would b a good practice to include  those buttons in a form with an action name. Then u can map that action with an action class where u can write this logic... otherwise u can write this code in your jsp if u know scriplets i.e. writing java code in jsp

Comment: Here the problem is that ,once the response is generated then i want to save the result which is in tabular format  to an excel file.If would have been like we have to save the data in parallel while it was generating i would have written the code there in jsp but i want like once the whole result is shown then we can save it

Comment: and do i need to write the above code in one servlet or somewhere else and i want like once save button is clicked... popup window opens and user can write the file name then save it